# EFCore Scaffold-DbContext Generate pluralized Models

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Reverse engineering using Scaffold-DbContext for Ef Core 1.0 generates Models with pluralized name.

I am using SQL Server 2014 with table name pluralized eg: Blogs, Posts... the Scaffold-DbContext generate model classes with Blogs, Posts but i want the model classes to be Blog, Post and DbSet to be Blogs and Posts.

Comment: Planned for 1.1 release. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/29/entity-framework-core-1-1-plans/

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the link. Is there any work around for now.

Comment: Version 6 had [code templates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp/) you could download and customize. You could use them to get your initial POCOs created then use them in core.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in EFCore v1.  However it is possible in EFCore v2. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52852282/1453411