# dotnet core 2.0 pluralize when scaffolding?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Setting my a .net core 2.x class library with ef core 2.  Have generated the scaffolding for the entities from my db schema.  However, I forgot to even check whether there as an option to pluralize the entity names.  I noticed this when I pulled over one my methods from a class library that uses EF 6.1 and the entities are pluralized.  Is there an option for this and to simply regenerate my entities as pluralized?

Comment: delete the model files and regenerate again

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281647/entityframework-core-database-first-approach-pluralizing-table-names

Comment: Best solution I have found so far: http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/12/entity-framework-core-2-pluralization-and-singularization/

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a class that implements the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IPluralizer` interface.  You can write your own, or use a NuGet package such as `Inflector`

   ```
   public class Pluralizer : IPluralizer
   {
       public string Pluralize(string name)
       {
           return Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(name) ?? name;
       }

       public string Singularize(string name)
       {
           return Inflector.Inflector.Singularize(name) ?? name;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Write a class that implements the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeServices` interface to register your `IPluralizer` implementation in your entity framework project.

   ```
   public class DesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
   {
       public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, Pluralizer>();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run (or rerun) your `Scaffold-DbContext` command from the package manager console as usual. If you want it to overwrite the previously generated code, you need the `-force` option.